# How to loop through unstructured multidimensional array

Tags: php, soap

I have a problem with a SOAP response from a webservice. The response is a multidimensional array, with a different structure per employee.

I tried using a foreach loop to retrieve all values and store them in a mysql database.

```
Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [department_id] => 1
                    [department_name] => Sales
                    [department_shortname] => SA
                    [hours] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Array
                                (
                                    [activity_id] => 1
                                    [start_date] => 2019-03-12
                                    [end_date] => 2019-03-12
                                    [start_time] => 10:00
                                    [end_time] => 14:20
                                    [hour_code] => 0
                                    [foreign_hour_code] => 20
                                    [amount] => 3.83
                                    [type] => productive
                                    [labor_cost] => 25.23
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [department_id] => 2
                    [department_name] => POS
                    [department_shortname] => POS
                    [hours] => Array
                        (
                            [item] => Array
                                (
                                    [activity_id] => 1
                                    [start_date] => 2019-03-12
                                    [end_date] => 2019-03-12
                                    [start_time] => 14:35
                                    [end_time] => 17:00
                                    [hour_code] => 0
                                    [foreign_hour_code] => 20
                                    [amount] => 2.42
                                    [type] => productive
                                    [labor_cost] => 24.67
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)


Array
(
    [item] => Array 
        (
            [department_id] => 2
            [department_name] => POS
            [department_shortname] => POS
            [hours] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [activity_id] => 1
                                    [start_date] => 2019-03-13
                                    [end_date] => 2019-03-13
                                    [start_time] => 07:30
                                    [end_time] => 12:00
                                    [hour_code] => 0
                                    [foreign_hour_code] => 20
                                    [amount] => 4.25
                                    [type] => productive
                                    [labor_cost] => 40.48
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [activity_id] => 1
                                    [start_date] => 
                                    [end_date] => 
                                    [start_time] => 
                                    [end_time] => 
                                    [hour_code] => 
                                    [foreign_hour_code] => 63
                                    [amount] => 2
                                    [type] => none
                                    [labor_cost] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

I tried this, but I don't get all of the data.

```
foreach($array as $employees)
{
  foreach($employees as $employee)
  {
    foreach($employee as $days)
    {
        foreach($days as $day)
        {
          foreach($day as $item)
          {
            foreach($item as $stores)
            {
              foreach($stores as $store)
              {
                foreach($store as $item1)
                {
                  foreach($item1 as $item2)
                  {
                    foreach($item2 as $hours)
                    {
                      foreach($hours as $hour)
                      {
                        foreach($hour as $booking)
                        {
                          /*
                          Store in DB per time registration.

                          $hours['department_id']
                          $hours['department_name']
                          $hours['department_shortname']

                          $booking[activity_id]
                          $booking[start_date]
                          $booking[end_date]
                          $booking[start_time]
                          $booking[end_time]
                          $booking[hour_code]
                          $booking[foreign_hour_code]
                          $booking[amount]
                          $booking[type]
                          $booking[labor_cost]
                          */
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to loop through all elements and store them in a database per time registration.

department_id | department_name | department_shortname | activity_id | start_date | end-date | start_time | end_time | hour_code | foreign_hour_code | amount | type | labor_cost

Comment: I can sort of guess what you want. What would be helpful is if showed us what you have tried so far. It gives us something to work with. BTW: The arrays are far from 'unstructured'.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I added my try. But because it's not the same structure per employee I can't get all results.

Comment: I see, the array is not always structured exactly the same way, so you cannot react to it rigidly. Instead react to the fields you encounter. What makes it harder to answer your question is that I can see you have shown us just a tiny part of the array, but I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I will start this answer by looking at the 'items'. What is noticable is that when there's only 1 item, in 'items', it is there right away, but if there are multiple items, an numeric array of items is used. So let us make some functions for that, just to correct that inconsistency.

```
function getItems($itemArray)
{
  // get the items in the item array
  $items = $itemArray['item'];
  // multiple items, in a numeric array, are returned as they are
  if (array_keys($items) === range(0, count($items) - 1) return $items;
  // whereas a single items is placed in a numeric array
  return [$items];
}
```

We can apply this to any 'items'.

Now I have a problem, because you haven't given me enough information. I don't know what the two arrays, you showed me, are a part of. So I will have to assume you can get them. They are items. Let's give them a name: 'startpoint'. This is chosen quite abitrary.

```
function processStartpoint($startpoint)
{
    // first get the department items
    $departments = getItems($startpoint);
    // process each department
    foreach ($departments as $department) {
        // get department info
        $departmentId        = $department['department_id'];
        $departmentName      = $department['department_name'];
        $departmentShortName = $department['department_shortname'];  
        // walk through each hour
        foreach (getItems($department['hours']) as $hour) {
            // get hour info
            $ActivityId      = $hour['activity_id'];
            $StartDate       = $hour['start_date']; 
            $EndDate         = $hour['end_date']; 
            $StartTime       = $hour['start_time']; 
            $EndTime         = $hour['end_time'];
            $HourCode        = $hour['hour_code']; 
            $ForeignHourCode = $hour['foreign_hour_code']; 
            $Amount          = $hour['amount'];
            $Type            = $hour['type'];
            $LaborCost       = $hour['labor_cost']; 
            /*
              store this in your database
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have no real way to check that this code works, but something like this will. The real trick is in the `getItems()` function, it reacts to the structure of the array.